# matlab for loop vectorization

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I was wondering if anyone could help me vectorize these for loops I have attempt a few time but have not been able to thanks in advance.

```
pixel_depth = 16; 
pixel_range = 2^pixel_depth -1;

for i=1:height

    for j=1:width

        for k=1:gaussianComponents

           mean(i,j,k) = rand*pixel_range; 

           weights(i,j,k) = 1/gaussianComponents; 

           pixelDeviation(i,j,k) = diviationNew; 

       end

    end

 end
```

Thank you for any help....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mean = rand(height, width, gaussianComponents) * pixel_range;

weights = 1/gaussianComponents * ones(height, width, gaussianComponents);

pixelDeviation = diviationNew * ones(height, width, gaussianComponents);
```

Note that `mean` is a bad name for a variable, as it will hide the `mean` function.

Comment: I am quite new to matlab so this may be a simple error, thank you for your answer I added this into matlab but it gives me an error saying repmat could have to many arguments, could you help with the error?

Comment: It seems to mee you want to assign every entry of weight the same value, which `weight=ones(height,width,gaussianComponents)*value` will do (like for `pixelDeviation`). Note also that `mean` in the answer above is not yet scaled by `pixelRange`.

Comment: @arne: You are absolutely right.  Thank you.  I've now fixed my answer (hopefully).

Comment: thank you that has fixed that, I still have a little problem I think it is from this line of code mean = rand(height, width, gaussianComponents); this does not seem to work I am not sure why I am finding it hard to debug compared to the original line as it is so different. I just wanted to check that it is doing the same idea? thank you again.

Comment: thanks arne.b I think the scaling issue it my current problem do you know how I could scale the mean by pixel range without a four loop? thank you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help after that I think I understand more about vectorizing four loops I just wanted to check my understanding: @arne.b and @Oli Charlesworth could you please confirm this is the same:  
for k=1:gussianComponents

w(i,j,k) = (1-alpha)*w(i,j,k) + alpha;

end 

is this the same as 

w = (1-alpha)*w(C) + alpha;

Thank you